# Keras model.fit() fails with ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to train a multi-output Keras model using a custom data generator. The model suppose to classify the mammography images by BIRADS categories(1-5) and density(A-D). I expect model to return two labels: birads category and density. The model should use two features. While running the model.fit() method, I'm encountering a ValueError related to incompatible shapes between my model's output and the ground truth labels. Specifically, the error is:
ValueError: Shapes (None, 5) and (None, 1) are incompatible.
Please find the error details and my code below.

#### What I did:

I have verified that the shapes of the inputs, outputs, and weights are what I expect them to be within the generator.
I have checked the model summary to ensure that the output shapes of my model match the shapes of the target labels.
I have tried to convert batch_labels_density into Int in order to overcome the error.
Looks I have 1D dimensions arrays (batch_labels_birads, batch_labels_density).
Moreover, I cannot use to_categorical() and one-hot encode my labels as I have multi-classificational labels with sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

Why am I getting this error and how to resolve it?

#### Error Traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e97964b44762> in <cell line: 132>()
    130 model.summary()
    131 
--> 132 history = model.fit(
    133     my_data_generator(
    134         training_data,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1055, in train_step
        return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in compute_metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 605, in update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/metrics/confusion_metrics.py", line 1485, in update_state  **
        return metrics_utils.update_confusion_matrix_variables(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 674, in update_confusion_matrix_variables
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
```

### My Data Generator:

```
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install pydicom

import numpy as np
import pydicom
import cv2

def my_data_generator(df, sample_weights_birads, sample_weights_density, batch_size=150):
    # img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255.)

    mapping_dict_density = {'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3}

    while True:
        # Select files (IDs) and labels for the batch
        batch_indices = np.random.choice(a=len(df), size=batch_size)
        batch_df = df.iloc[batch_indices]

        # Initialize batch arrays
        batch_images = []
        batch_labels_birads = []
        batch_labels_density = []
        batch_features = []
        batch_weights_birads = []
        batch_weights_density = []

        for i, original_idx in enumerate(batch_indices):
            row = batch_df.iloc[i]

            img_id = row['image_id']
            study_id = row['study_id']


            img_path = f".....dicom"

            img = pydicom.dcmread(img_path).pixel_array


            # Resize image based on the height and width from CSV if needed
            def conditional_resize(img, target_height=3518, target_width=2800):
               pass # image resizing is happening here

            img = conditional_resize(img)

            # Append to batch
            batch_images.append(img)
            batch_labels_birads.append(row['breast_birads'])
            batch_labels_density.append(mapping_dict_density.get(row['breast_density'], -1))
            batch_features.append([row['laterality'], row['view_position']])

            batch_weights_birads.append(sample_weights_birads[original_idx])
            batch_weights_density.append(sample_weights_density[original_idx])


        batch_images = np.array(batch_images)
        batch_labels_birads = np.squeeze(np.array(batch_labels_birads))
        batch_labels_density = np.squeeze(np.array(batch_labels_density))

        batch_features = np.array(batch_features)
        batch_weights_birads = np.array(batch_weights_birads)
        batch_weights_density = np.array(batch_weights_density)

        print('\n birads_output', batch_labels_birads, '\n density_output', batch_labels_density)
        print("\n Shape of training image_input:", batch_images.shape,
              "\n Shape of training features:", batch_features.shape,
              "\n Shape of training birads labels:", batch_labels_birads.shape,
              "\n Shape of training birads weights:", batch_weights_birads.shape,
              "\n Shape of training density labels:", batch_labels_density.shape,
              "\n Shape of training density weights:", batch_weights_density.shape,
              '\n batch_labels_birads', type(batch_labels_birads), 'batch_weights_density', type(batch_weights_density),
              '\n batch_labels_birads.shape', type(batch_labels_birads.shape), 'batch_weights_density.shape', type(batch_weights_density.shape))


        yield {'image_input': batch_images, 'feature_input': batch_features}, \
            {'birads_output': batch_labels_birads, 'density_output': batch_labels_density}, \
            {'birads_output': batch_weights_birads, 'density_output': batch_weights_density}
```

### My Model Building:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import collections
from collections import Counter




num_channels = 1  # Assuming grayscale images

standard_height, standard_width = 3518, 2800
image_input = Input(shape=(standard_height, standard_width, num_channels), name="image_input")

# Define CNN layers
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(image_input)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

# Flatten and dense layers
flatten = Flatten()(x)

# Define tabular data input layer for two features: 'laterality' and 'view_position'
feature_input = Input(shape=(2,), name='feature_input')  # Two features

# Concatenate flattened image data and feature data
merged = Concatenate()([flatten, feature_input])

new_layer = Dense(12, activation='relu')(merged)  # or any number of units you want

birads_output = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='birads_output')(new_layer)
density_output = Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='density_output')(new_layer)

# Complete the model
model = Model(inputs=[image_input, feature_input], outputs=[birads_output, density_output])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss={'birads_output': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    'density_output': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'birads_output': ['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc_birads')],
                       'density_output': ['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc_density')]
                       })


checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/Callbacks/First_Attempt_Batches',
                             save_weights_only=True,
                             save_freq=150)  # Save after every 150 images (i.e., one batch)



def get_sample_weights(y):
    counter = Counter(y)
    max_val = float(max(counter.values()))
    sample_weights = np.array([max_val / counter[i] for i in y])
    return sample_weights

y_train_birads = training_data['breast_birads'].values
y_train_density = training_data['breast_density'].values

y_val_birads = validation_data['breast_birads'].values
y_val_density = validation_data['breast_density'].values



# Assuming y_train_birads and y_train_density contain your actual training labels
sample_weights_birads_train = get_sample_weights(y_train_birads)
sample_weights_density_train = get_sample_weights(y_train_density)

sample_weights_birads_val = get_sample_weights(y_val_birads)
sample_weights_density_val = get_sample_weights(y_val_density)

# Map the class weights to the individual samples in the dataset
sample_weights_train = {'birads_output': sample_weights_birads_train,
                        'density_output': sample_weights_density_train}

sample_weights_val = {'birads_output': sample_weights_birads_val,
                      'density_output': sample_weights_density_val}

print('\n sample_weights_val', sample_weights_val,'\n sample_weights_train', sample_weights_train )
print("\n Shape of model output:", model.output_shape,
        "\n Shape of image_input:", image_input.shape,
      "\n Shape of feature_input:", feature_input.shape,
      "\n Shape of birads label:", y_train_birads.shape,
      "\n Shape of birads weight:", sample_weights_birads_train.shape,
      "\n Shape of density label:", y_train_density.shape,
      "\n Shape of density weight:", sample_weights_density_train.shape,
      )

model.summary()

history = model.fit(
    my_data_generator(
        training_data,
        batch_size=150,
        # birads_output =
        sample_weights_birads=sample_weights_birads_train,
        sample_weights_density=sample_weights_density_train,
    ),
    # steps_per_epoch=len(training_data) // 150,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=my_data_generator(
        validation_data,
        batch_size=32,
        sample_weights_birads=sample_weights_birads_val,
        sample_weights_density=sample_weights_density_val,
    ),
    # validation_steps=len(validation_data) // 32,
    callbacks=[checkpoint]
)
```

While execution I see these printings:

```
sample_weights_val {'birads_output': array([14.56060606, 14.56060606,  2.53562005, ...,  1.        ,
        1.        ,  1.        ]), 'density_output': array([1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.])} 
 sample_weights_train {'birads_output': array([ 2.94959552,  2.94959552,  2.94959552, ..., 18.66141732,
        2.94959552,  2.94959552]), 'density_output': array([1., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.])}

 Shape of model output: [(None, 5), (None, 4)] 
 Shape of image_input: (None, 3518, 2800, 1) 
 Shape of feature_input: (None, 2) 
 Shape of birads label: (14000,) 
 Shape of birads weight: (14000,) 
 Shape of density label: (14000,) 
 Shape of density weight: (14000,)
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 image_input (InputLayer)       [(None, 3518, 2800,  0           []                               
                                 1)]                                                              
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)                (None, 3516, 2798,   320         ['image_input[0][0]']            
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 1758, 1399,   0           ['conv2d[0][0]']                 
                                32)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)              (None, 1756, 1397,   18496       ['max_pooling2d[0][0]']          
                                64)                                                               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 878, 698, 64  0          ['conv2d_1[0][0]']               
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 flatten (Flatten)              (None, 39222016)     0           ['max_pooling2d_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 feature_input (InputLayer)     [(None, 2)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 39222018)     0           ['flatten[0][0]',                
                                                                  'feature_input[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 12)           470664228   ['concatenate[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 birads_output (Dense)          (None, 5)            65          ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 density_output (Dense)         (None, 4)            52          ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 470,683,161
Trainable params: 470,683,161
Non-trainable params: 0

birads_output [1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2
 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 4 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 4 2 1 3 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 4 3
 2 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1
 2 1 3 1 3 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
 5 2] 
 density_output [3 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3
 2 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2]

 Shape of training image_input: (150, 3518, 2800) 
 Shape of training features: (150, 2) 
 Shape of training birads labels: (150,) 
 Shape of training birads weights: (150,) 
 Shape of training density labels: (150,) 
 Shape of training density weights: (150,) 
 batch_labels_birads <class 'numpy.ndarray'> batch_weights_density <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
 batch_labels_birads.shape <class 'tuple'> batch_weights_density.shape <class 'tuple'>
Epoch 1/2
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I've reshaped two of my output labels to the shape (batch_size, 1).

```
batch_labels_birads = batch_labels_birads.reshape(-1, 1)  
batch_labels_density = batch_labels_density.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error comes from the shape of your labels... I would look into the behavior of your np.squeeze method. You may want to remove it so that the shape of your model output is aligned with the labels

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, I've dived into the labels. Eventually, I remove squeeze method and reshaped my labels in the data_generator and the model. So I overcame the shape mismatch error. However, I've got another error related to data types: "Cast string to float is not supported". I hope this new issue isn't due to my recent changes.